# Caterpillar identification - found on a coffee plant inside a house

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Today, I've found a twig-like caterpillar hanging down from my homegrown coffee plant (which explained why some of the plant's leaves appear to be eaten away). What specie is this insect? It was about 2 cm long, I live in Central Europe.

Image of the caterpillar is attached below, and here is the [movie of me annoying it](https://i.imgur.com/S1GvkQe.mp4).

[image]